# Export Competitor’s Members - Telegram - Opensource

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Is there any Telegram Bot to Export your competitor’s group/channel members and add to your own group/channel. Excellent way to grow your telegram group.

Comment: There is no way to do that with the Bot API.

Comment: There was a demo posted by Youtubers. Here is the link. https://youtu.be/CNrrbqddlQk

Comment: That's regular client API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with the telegram bot api and it is not allowed to do so otherwise. It is not permittet by the Telegram Terms of Service.
If you however try to do it anyways it is considered spam/flood and will be detected and reported, your accounts get restricted and will likely get blocked from telegram.
Also something like that is considered unfair competition by most jurisdictions and might get you legal charges.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Telegram Group Crawler](http://telmemeber.com/tools/crawler) to export members from any public group. 
but adding them to any groups without their consent is violating Telegram's terms of use.

Comment: Can we add the Member Dynamical more than 100 Members to the Group Dynamically? By Crawler. We get the member Information alone. How it will be possible to Add more member by BOT?

Comment: Check the Link. Need Something Similar to the link. Here is the demo posted by Youtubers. Here is the link. youtu.be/CNrrbqddlQk

Comment: @BensonKB check telmemeber.com